# How to change my profile "language" (The part next to <> under the profile pic)

Tags: github

Is there any way I can change this profile element that seems to be what language I tend to program in?

As you can see now, it currently says "Perl" (I've never coded in perl! My work is usually in C++) 
[image]

I've seen a few different people on my follow/following list with their main languages separated by commas:

[image]

I couldn't find this is any of the profile settings pages, is it automatically detected?

Comment: These type of GitHub questions are more for http://WebApps.StackExchange.com as you're just setting profile info here, not actually doing any coding

Comment: Okay, sorry about that! I got the answer anyway so this can be closed/deleted.

Comment: They don’t seem to do this now.

Answer (score 8):

It is automatically detected from the languages in your repositories. The open source [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist) library developed by Github is used to detect languages in those repositories.

There is no way to edit the listed languages via settings.

Comment: If that was true mine would probably say C++ and C#, but it says "C#, Python, R"... what the hell is R? I don't even know.

Comment: Have you forked repositories that have those languages?

Comment: My forks include C++ mostly and one with C#, and Github is recognizing the languages on those forks correctly.

Comment: Must be a problem in the implementation of the feature, either within Linguist or during the addition of primary languages to your profile. I'd lean toward it being the latter, since they aren't showing up incorrectly in your repos.

Comment: I forked, did some fixes and had the original owner pull it in.  That is what I got tagged with even though all of my own repos are a different language!

Comment: Looks like it has been removed.